# What is perfect pitch,variance and speed values in flite tts for iphone

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, text-to-speech, flite

Hi i am successfully added flite-tts(flite-1.4) and i am here the voice for my input text but the problem is some times the words are not clearly to heard,

can any one suggest what are the best values(pitch,variance) to here the input text .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm there isn't really a 'best' value for those.
I suppose you know you can choose which voice to use  ;-)

I use the female voice: `cmu_us_flt`
and have these settings:

- **duration_stretch**: 1.2
- **target_mean**: 1.2
- **target_stddev**: 2.0

although it still clearly sounds like a computer voice it is still perfect for my app and it works.

Hope this helps!

Comment: how to import cmu_us_flt in flite-1.4-iphone as there are no such voice included ..